# Access Shopify Property via post request

Tags: shopify

I want to access the shopify api object to get (paymentMethod , paymentReference , refundedAmount and risklevel).

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the shop using the API, and ask for the order(s) of interest. All the payment information for order is available either with the order itself, or by asking for the transactions belonging to the order. All clearly documented in the [API documentation](http://www.shopify.com/developers/api/).